# async function Unexpected token, expected (

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use the async function as suggested in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html) but I am getting this error `Unexpected token, expected (`

```
async function getMoviesFromApi() {
    try {
      let response = await fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json');
      let responseJson = await response.json();
      return responseJson.movies;
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

error is on this line `async function getMoviesFromApi() {`

Its say **You can also use the proposed ES2017 async/await syntax in a React Native app:**

Should not it just work ? What wrong I am doing ?

Comment: `Unexpected token, expected (` where it happens?

Comment: Oh sorry , right on the function decleration line

Comment: try using the promise way as mentioned in the documentation.(.then way )

Comment: Which version of react native you use ?

Comment: @soywod  I am using react native 0.43 with expo.

Comment: @IsmailIqbal yeah that work , but I am curiuos why this doesn't work , and I just kinda prefer this async way. Code looks more clean. :)

Comment: are you in a class context ? If it is, remove the function keyword

Answer (score 8):

Try taking the function keyword out of the declaration. So instead of

```
async function getMoviesFromApi()
```

Use:

```
async getMoviesFromApi()
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

In ES6 you can do `let getMoviesFromApi = async() => {}`

Answer (score 0):

Also have the function bound in a constructor up top

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.<async function> = this.<async function>.bind(this)
}
```